# Alignment of Horizontal Layout in Vaadin

Tags: java, css, vaadin7

I have a mainlayout which is an absolute layout and inside that there is a horizontal layout which I want to allign in center and when the screen resolution is decreased then the horizontal layout should also move until its minnimum widht without decreading its own width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Java part, set:

```
absoluteLayout.setSizeFull();
absoluteLayout.addStyleName("full-size");
```

and

```
horizontalLayout.setWidth("90%");
horizontalLayout.addStyleName("horizontalContainer");
```

Then in CSS:

```
.full-size .v-absolutelayout-wrapper:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.horizontalContainer{
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
min-width: 800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common pattern. For the horizontal centering you can do:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

You can simply set a width to the block element by doing:

```
width: 99px;
```

edit: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lhjc0pb/)

Comment: " margin : 0 auto; " this is not working as in vaadin it needs some position and using this the horizontal layout is just alligned to 0px of the screen rather than coming in center.